# SQL NOT LIKE with subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, jpql

How can i make this work?

```
SELECT a.city 
FROM Address a 
WHERE a.city NOT LIKE ANY '(
SELECT a2.city FROM Address a2 WHERE a2.id = ANY (
SELECT ca.customerAddressPK.addressId FROM CustomerAddress ca WHERE ca.customerAddressPK.customerId = ANY(
SELECT c.id FROM Customer c WHERE c.firstName = 'niko')))'
```

So I want to get a list of cities which are not the same as cities with niko addresses. the address entity and the customer entity have many to many relation.

Is there an alternative where i can run this query?

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you here. Certainly what you have isn't going to work; it's not valid T-SQL. Also, what does this question have to do with [tag:jpql]?

Comment: `ca.customerAddressPK.customerId` is not valid a valid column reference. This is but one reason why it is far better to post a script that others can run to understand your issue. And perhaps you assume there is only one customer with first name = 'niko' - is that safe? Probably not but the correct code depends on your schema and your actual goal.

Answer (score 0):

> So I want to get a list of cities which are not the same as cities with niko addresses.

You can use aggregation for this query:

```
SELECT a.city 
FROM Address a join
     CustomerAddress ca
     on ca.addressId = a.id join
     Customer c
     on ca.customerId = c.id
GROUP BY a.city
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN c.firstName = 'niko' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Note:  This assumes that all addresses have a city.  That seems to be an assumption of your attempt as well.